# Vector Calculus identity valid?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

If $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{B}$ for all $\mathbf{v}$, does it imply $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}$? Can there be a simple proof for this?

Comment: $\mathbf v\cdot(\mathbf A-\mathbf B)=0$

Comment: But can $(A-B)$ not always be perpendicular to $v$?

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{B}$ implies $\mathbf v\cdot(\mathbf A-\mathbf B)=0$. Then take $\mathbf v = (\mathbf A-\mathbf B)$ to obtain $\Vert \mathbf A-\mathbf B \Vert^2=0$ and hence $\mathbf A=\mathbf B$.

*Provided of course that by $ \cdot $, you mean an inner product!*